# How to call an Async API in a synchronous fashion?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

Suppose you have a typical async design-pattern API that has

1. A method called Start that launches the async process
2. A callback that is called when the process completes

How would you call this API in a synchronous fashion using .NET 3.5 without blocking the message pump during the call?

Comment: Of course you have to block something if you want it synchronously - you can do this easily using a `ManualResetEvent` which you set in the callback (can of course be a lambda/closure) and you just `.Wait` for it.

Comment: Why do you want to call this function in a Synchronous fashon? Also calling something synchronously literally means "Block until it finishes", so if you are not blocking the UI thread which the message pump runs on, what do you want to block? Can you please update your question showing the intended use of this function, it will give us a much better picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @scottchamberlain: suppose there is no synchronous function to call in this API.

Comment: @CarstenKönig: waitOne() will block UI thread and stop message pump

Comment: @Lloyd: synchronous means that I would like to wait for the result of the asynchronous call.

Comment: @Denis `waitOne` or whatever will block the thread **you are on** - that is what *synchronous* **is** - it's your responsibility to choose the right thread

Comment: @CarstenKönig: That is the reason why I said waitone won't work. I am looking for a method like "Join" which supposedly will allow the message pump to work... I am not having any luck with Thread.Join although documentation says it should work.

Comment: @Denis [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx) will also block the thread ...I say it again: if you don't want to block *any* thread you have to go async (BTW: where does the documentation say otherwise - it says: "Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates." rather clearly)

Comment: @CarstenKönig: The reason I am going synchronous is that this function always used to be synchronous (the new & improved & faster api is async) and callers of this function expect a return value. I can't go async because how would I return a value for backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Denis then it always blocked the calling thread ... so no change here (and no - please don't ask for this "DoEvents" anti-pattern ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61009/discussion-between-denis-and-carsten-konig).

Comment: In case of 'changing' an API: Do not change the API Just add a *Async version of the method. That way you still support the old API. You could mark it as Depricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait for the result (synchronous call) but do not want to block the message pump (assuming you mean the UI thread) you would have to use a separate thread to do the call (and wait for it)

Using async and await:

```
// current thread is the UI thread
// so create/use a Task to wait for the call
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { DoJobAsync().Wait()});
```

The UI thread creates a Task (T1) and returns immediately. T1 runs on a different thread. This thread calls an asynchronous function (it returns another task T2) so to wait for the result of the asynchronous T1 calls Wait on T2.

This is pretty contrived:

1. the intend of the asynchronous method is to be executed asynchronously, probably because it will take quite some time to finish.
2. The task T1 allows the UI to continue with the next lines of the calling code (opposed to using async/await from the UI thread which registers a continuation. But now you might need get the resulks from T1 in some other way.

Comment: I only have .NET 3.5 so no async/await. How would you do it in .NET 3.5?

Comment: @Denis - in .NET 3.5 you would most likely use the callback pattern

Comment: @denis - That depends on the API you are using. If you create the threads yourself you could use thread.join to wait for a thread. Or if the inner function sets a waithandle you could wait for that. If the inner function accepts a callback set a waithandle in the callback and wait for that